# SQL server Tablockx hint to block concurrent transactions reading same rows from a table

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to address duplicate key inserts due to race condition which we wanted to avoid by appropriate locks.

This is the procedure ( SQL 2017)

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
    @Ref VARCHAR(50)
AS
    DECLARE @nextId VARCHAR(8); 
-- Find the lowest id that does not exist in the table
    SET @nextId = (SELECT TOP 1 PId +1
                    FROM (SELECT Id, lag(Id) 
                            OVER (ORDER BY Id) PId FROM mytable) e
                    WHERE pId <> (Id-1)
                    ORDER BY Id);

    -- Pad zeros to the left up to a length of 8
    SET @nextId = right('00000000'+ rtrim(@nextId), 8);

    -- Insert a new row with the value and the missing id
    INSERT INTO dbo.mytable
    OUTPUT @nextId
    VALUES (@Ref, @nextId)
GO
```

We dont want the concurrent transactions to read the same record from mytable, which will result in a duplicate nextid in one of the sessions and that will fail because of the unique constraint.

I checked serializable isolation level, even that does not seem to fit my case because it still allows concurrent transactions to read the same rows and only blocks one of the inserts which eventually ends up as duplicate insert anyways.

What are the other options i have here. From the doc, TABLOCKX seems to be the only option for me. But since that is exclusive lock, I wanted to check if there any other granular lock available which will help my case.

Basically i want to lock a row exclusively and that should not be visible for any DML operations in any other transactions.

Edit 1: Unfortunately we cannot use sequence because of the limitation in our application design.

Thanks

Comment: [Sequence Tables](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/10/sequence-tables.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `TABLOCK`, you only need `UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK` hints.

You can also combine it into one statement.

```sql
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
    @Ref VARCHAR(50)
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (Ref, PId)
    OUTPUT inserted.PId
SELECT
  @Ref,
  FORMAT(ISNULL(MAX(TRY_CAST(mt.PId AS bigint)), 0) + 1, '00000000')
FROM dbo.mytable mt WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK);
```

You should have an index on `PId` otherwise it will indeed lock the whole table.

---

Obviously in real life you wouldn't actually use such code. You would use a computed column together with `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing this (very similar to what Erik has suggested using a sequence table), but you don't need one.

The first method is to use a computed column to get you the leading zero as the identity value.  You can do that this way although it does add an additional column to your table.

```
/** NO SEQUENCE OBJECT **/

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
    (
    PID AS CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Pkid), 8)) PERSISTED NOT NULL
    , ReferenceValue VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , Pkid INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Mytable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PID)
    )
```

The second way is how I would do it and uses a SEQUENCE object instead of a sequence table, but gets you to the same place.  See here [MSSQL SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for more details on it, but you could do this as well.

```
/** WITH SEQUENCE OBJECT **/

CREATE SEQUENCE MyTableSequence AS INT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTableSequences
    (
    PID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTableSequence DEFAULT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), NEXT VALUE FOR MyTableSequence), 8)) 
    , ReferenceValue NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT PK_MyTableSequences PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PID)
    )
```

With the Sequence object, you are guaranteed a unique value on each call to it  although if it is queried very quickly (really, really quickly so not likely) you may get gaps.

UPDATE

Since it appears that you are unable to implement any of the better solutions involving a sequence table/object, that leaves modifications to the procedure you have outlined.  There is no amount of locking that will help you here since you can't lock a record that doesn't exist yet.  (I mean, you could lock the entire table, but that would block readers and writers for the duration of the insert, which will lead to significant blocking, given that at least your inserts are happening fast enough to cause unique index violations.

This is my next best solution.  It does two things.  One is that it makes the insert a single operation.  The other is that it uses try/catch and some max retry logic to try multiple times.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
    (
    @Ref VARCHAR(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    /** Working Variables **/
    DECLARE @NextID VARCHAR(8)
    DECLARE @MaxRetries INT = 3
    DECLARE @CurrentTry INT = 1

    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE
        (
        ID VARCHAR(8) NULL
        )

    /** Attempt this until @NextID is populated OR we have exceeded our max tries **/
    WHILE @NextID IS NULL
        AND @CurrentTry <= @MaxRetries
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY

            INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable 
            OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ResultTable (ID)
            VALUES ((SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (MAX(ID) + 1)), 8) FROM dbo.MyTable)
                    , @Ref
                    )

            SET @NextID = (SELECT TOP (1) ID FROM @ResultTable)

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

            SET @CurrentTry = @CurrentTry + 1

        END CATCH       

    END

END
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Updated my question. Unfortunately we cannot use sequence because of limitations in application design. How can I achieve a truly serial execution in my case with locks

Comment: I don't know if locks are going to accomplish your goal, or if they do then you will start seeing blocking.   Are you able to change the procedure?

Comment: you could try (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) & you'll need an explicit transaction too. TBH I think the other suggestions are better but maybe this answers your question

Comment: @JonathanFite - if any of the isolation levels or lock hints is not going to help in my use case, and changing sp is the only option, then I have explore it. For now, we are ok even if this is strict isolation level and introduce blocking because we are trying to avoid the race condition and this table does not have any other workload apart from this.

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 - I think (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) wont help my use case. Because from what I have read, rowlock hint only prevents SQL engine from escalating row level lock and it is not going to lock a row and make it invisible for other concurrent sessions

Comment: Did you look up what UPDLOCK does ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough to serialize the code without involving the actual data in the (b)locking semantics?

If so, consider sp_getapplock and sp_releaseapplock. I.e., lock just some name you make up, and use an appropriate lock mode so the "second" will be waiting for the "first" to release its lock.